# Spring-Security OKTA Integration - OAuth2AuthorizedClient is always null

Tags: web, spring-security, okta

I am using Spring 5.3.6 (not spring-boot) and Java 1.8 (I know it is a very old version, but it is the client's requirement).

I have a traditional web application and I am trying to integrate it with OKTA instead of Spring LDAP. However, I am facing two issues:

1. The redirect URI is not coming to the controller even after trying all available options.
2. In one of the configured Interceptors, I can see that the Principal is OAuth2AuthenticationToken, but when I try to get the OAuth2AuthorizedClient, it is always null.

I would appreciate any help you can provide with these issues. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(authenticationToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authenticationToken.getName());

@Controller
public class OAuth2LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService; 
    
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OAuth2LoginController.class.getName());
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login/oauth2/code/*")
    public String handleAuthorizationResponse(@RequestParam("code") String code, 
                                               @RequestParam("state") String state, 
                                               Principal principal) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "code" + code);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "state" + state);
        return "redirect:/home"; 
    }
}
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true, prePostEnabled=true )
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository repository;
    InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService service ;

@Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
           .headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable()
            .and()
           .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**", "/help/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/login/oauth2/code/okta").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/login/oauth2/code/*").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()
           .oauth2Login()
           .and()
           .oauth2ResourceServer()
           .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
           .and()
           .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults());
   }

   @Bean
   public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService() {
       if (service == null) {
           service = new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository());
       } 
       return service;
   }

   @Bean
   public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
       if (repository == null) {
           List<ClientRegistration> registrations = Collections.singletonList(getRegistration());
           repository = new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(registrations);
       }
       return repository;
   }
   
      
   @Bean
   JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
       return JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation("https://okta_domain/oauth2/default");
   }
   
   private ClientRegistration getRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("okta")
                .clientId("client_id")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE) 
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
                .scope("openid", "offline_access", "mbc")
                .authorizationUri("https://okta_domain/oauth2/default/v1/authorize")
                .tokenUri("https://okta_domain/oauth2/default/v1/token")
                .userInfoUri("https://okta_domain/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo")
                .jwkSetUri("https://okta_domain/oauth2/default/v1/keys")
                .clientName("okta")
                .build();
    }
   }
```

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}